# how to send sms in regional language using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

im using textlocal.in api for sending bulk sms, when i type message in regional language it shows error

```
{"errors":[{"code":204,"message":"Invalid message content"}],"status":"failure"}
```

is there any way of sending regional language please help me?

```
var http = require('http');
var urlencode = require('urlencode'); 

var msg = 'ಅನುವಾದಿಸಿ';
var toNumber = '9731750371';
var username = 'dinesh@cantern.in';
var hash = '171f2176f6a24f1d219028011d5bff7b9eac1a3ff91873de62af429a736da26'; // The hash key could be found under Help->All Documentation->Your hash key. Alternatively you can use your Textlocal password in plain text.
var sender = 'txtlcl';
var data = 'username=' + username + '&hash=' + hash + '&sender=' + sender + '&numbers=' + toNumber + '&message=' + msg;
var options = {
  host: 'api.textlocal.in', path: '/send?' + data
};
callback = function (response) {
  var str = '';//another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });//the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}//console.log('hello js'))
http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find solution for this ? If yes what did you do to solve it? I am having the same error in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install

```
npm install i18n-nodejs --save
```

download the locale language json file and use this code

```
var config = {
"lang": "ar",
"langFile": "./../../locale.json"//relative path to index.js file  
}
var i18n = require('i18n-nodejs')(config.lang, config.langFile);
```

where "ar" refers to Arabic language

and set character-set to UTF-8 like this

```
response.header("Content-Type", "html/text; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: hi harsh there is an Error: Cannot find module 'locale.json', my index.js and local.js files are in one folder.

Comment: that "ar" in "lang":"ar" means Arabic language . you have find code for your language of choice .And that locale.json file should be created by you refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-nodejs

Comment: first try buy just changing  charset to UTF-8 . Then go for Internalization

Comment: there is an Error: Cannot find module 'locale.json' , i have kept both files in same folder.

Comment: if you have kept both files in same folder relative path will be like ./locale.json not ./../../locale.json

Comment: harsh sorry for your time, your code is working but when i send sms using textlocal.in it again shows the same error please look at the error , console.log is printing text but not sending sms :         ಕನ್ನಡ
{"errors":[{"code":204,"message":"Invalid message content"}],"status":"failure"}